# How to compute central stability (including strength, betweenness and closeness) of a network?

Tags: r, statistics, network-analysis

[image]

[image]

I am conducting a network analysis using the EBIC Glasso function, examining clinical symptoms and dimensions of insight in schizophrenia. I am at the step where I am trying to compute centrality stability for the Network using the bootnet function, however, when I go to do this, only the measure "strength" appears, when normally, betweenness and closeness should also appear. I even included the bootnet "statistics" argument, yet still only strength appeared.

What is wrong here and how I can fix this?

I tried :

```
plot(bootnet(Network, nBoots = 1000, type = "case", nCores = 4, statistics = c("strength", "betweenness", "closeness")))
```

It plotted the correct idea of a graph, but only showed the strength line and not closeness or betweenness.

Comment: Sorry I can't be more helpful, but anyway you might try stats.stackexchange.com for questions of this kind.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the `statistics` argument in both `bootnet(...)` and `plot(...)`. I would also suggest you save the bootnet results before plotting:

```
res <- bootnet(...., statistics = c("strength","closeness","betweenness"))
plot(res, statistics = c("strength","closeness","betweenness"))
```

However, do note that closeness and betweenness are not included by default for good reasons, as they are often not stable. The plot you show already shows that the stability of strength is questionable, so I wouldn't expect very stable results for closeness and betweenness.